# Building an uncountable number of random variables

Tags: probability-theory

Can one build a probability space on which one can define an uncountable number of independent Bernoulli or uniform random variables?

What about an uncountable number of independent Brownian motions?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_process

Comment: Could you be more precise?

Comment: Look at section "Bernoulli process" on given link - is it sufficient example?

Comment: Kolomogorov's Existence Theorem is  a very general theorem in this direction. It proves existencs of not just independent random variables but also dependent one's with given finite dimensional joint distributions.

Comment: How do you prove with KET that you can build an uncountable number of independent Brownian motions?